# why "runtime error on text 1" will occur?

Tags: c

```c
#include<stdio.h>
inline long long int abs(long long int a){
    if(a>=0) return a;
    return -a;  
}
inline long long int MIN(long long int a,long long int b){
    return a<b?a:b;
}

int main(){
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    
    for(int j=0;j<t;j++){
        long long int a,b;
        scanf("%lld%lld",&a,&b);
        long long int sub=abs(a-b);
        long long int min=MIN(a,b);
        long long int i=0;
        while(a%sub||b%sub) {
            if(i>=min) break;
            i++;a++;b++;
        }
        min=MIN(i,min);
        
        printf("%lld %lld",sub,min);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
Input
4
8 5
1 2
4 4
3 9
Checker Log
Exit code is -1073741676
```

I think my code is perfect and it runs perfectly in my IDE, but in codeforces over ten times, it said that there was a runtime error on text 1. I don't know why.

Comment: "_runtime error on text 1_" doesn't mean anything to us. You'd need to show _text 1_ for that to give us context.  We also do not magically understand what you want your program to do. Describe it, in detail, please.

Comment: Please give the exact input.

Comment: Your `abs` function exhibits undefined behaviour when passed `LLONG_MIN` (probably returning a negative value in practice).

Comment: Input
4
8 5
1 2
4 4
3 9
Checker Log
Exit code is -1073741676

Comment: maybe my code use too many cycle

Answer (score 1):

When `a == b`, `abs` returns 0, and then you have a division by 0 here: `(a % sub || b % sub)` which triggers the problem.

Division by 0 in C is *undefined behaviour* (google that term), and that explains why in some environnments you get away with it and in others the programs stops.

This is a modified version of your program which makes that clear:

- I renamed `abs` to `myabs`, otherwise `abs` collides with the standard ^abs`function from`stdlib.h`which is needed for the`exit` function
- I added a check, son the program stops if `a == b`.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

inline long long int myabs(long long int a) {
  if (a >= 0) return a;
  return -a;
}
inline long long int MIN(long long int a, long long int b) {
  return a < b ? a : b;
}

int main() {
  int t;
  scanf("%d", &t);

  for (int j = 0; j < t; j++) {
    long long int a, b;
    scanf("%lld%lld", &a, &b);

    if (a == b)
    {
      printf("\nBummer.\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    long long int sub = myabs(a - b);
    long long int min = MIN(a, b);
    long long int i = 0;

    while (a % sub || b % sub) {
      if (i >= min) break;
      i++; a++; b++;
    }
    min = MIN(i, min);

    printf("%lld %lld", sub, min);
  }
  return 0;
}
```